# Expected type 'Word' (matched generic type '_T'), got 'Character' instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm working on some stack object and encountered a weird warning:
Expected type 'Word' (matched generic type '_T'), got 'Character' instead

I initialized a data struct that has a stack:

```
def __init__(self, text, actions):
    self._stack = []
    self._stack.append(Word())
```

And then I try to insert another object typed to the stack, but I have this warning appearing.

```
 def act_s(self):
    self._stack.append(Character())
```

Why is this happening?
Python lists can handle multiple type object as far as I know.
Thanks!